# Background img changing when form is valid

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm creating a form for a web page using HTML, CSS and Angular JS.  I have managed to achieve what I want but I don't think its done in a very good way and was just wondering if there would be another way to achieve the same result?  (perhaps there is not but thought I would ask anyway).

Basically im using AngularJS form to validate my form. If the form is valid, it applies the `ng-valid` class to the for). Within my form, I display a background image of a red X if the form is invalid and a green tick if the form is valid.  As the `ng-valid` class is added as soon as the form is valid, I have the following CSS to change the image:

```
.ng-valid>div>div>div>div>a>div>div.regImg1{
     background-image: url('../img/green-tick.png');
 }
```

My standard CSS for this is:

```
.regImg1{
    background-image: url('../img/grey-tick.png');
}
```

While this works, I am aware that a change to the HTML would break it. I wonder if there is a more elegent way to do this, which doesn't break when the HTML changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [descendant](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/d/descendant/) selector, which is just a space separating the two selectors.

```
.ng-valid .regImg1 {
...
}
```

Comment: Excellent,  Thanks everyone for your input. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that is a concern with the html changing, seeing as the selector is so specific with child selectors.

a simple selector like this could do the job, without being specific to the markup structure

```
.ng-valid .regImg1{
    background-image: url('../img/green-tick.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using a whitespace between your parent and child elements, this will tell ***you want any child*** matching the child description inside the parent ***no matter how deep it is***.

This would give you the following:

```
.ng-valid .regImg1{
    background-image: url('../img/green-tick.png');
}
```